My VsCode doesn't have a build button in the menu bar
I am new to VsCode and I am trying to batch build a file/project (sln) folder and release it to x64 dll, but I cannot seem to find Build or Batch Build on the menu bar. I tried installing c/c++, SDK does that help?
menu bar
I tried installing c/c++, SDK does that help?. All I can do is to build ctrl + shift + b, but I don't know how does that work and it doesn't have a release folder after I use it.

is there a version of vscode where it has build button so I can batch build?

I got it what I need is Visual Studio with Desktop development with C++, thanks for the help

You can run file by here.

Or you can build and run file by terminal, you should research on google how to run file of your language which you are using by terminal of vscode.
I hope my suggestion helpful for you.

is there a version of vscode where it has build button so I can batch build?

that triangle button should not be used by anyone, it is not the way to work with VSC, it is a button from some extension, use tasks to build your code
